# Mysql select closest match from table

Tags: mysql, select, match, closest

I got a table that looks like that:

```
ID|DATA
1 | ok
4 | ok2
5 | kk
6 | same ok
7 | k
9 | yeah
```

I want to find the closest match(round down) to my id. When I pass

> id = 8

I want to select the raw `7 | K`

How do I do that in mySql

Comment: specify the server side scripting you use. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT   id, data
FROM     tbl
WHERE    id <= 8
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

Alternatively, here's another way you can do it without having to use `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT b.id, b.data
FROM   (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM tbl WHERE id <= 8) a
JOIN   tbl b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: it sounds like expensive solution, I think I need some how to limit it. I don't want him to select all the numbers and then sort them

Comment: @Babibu, see the alternative solution I just put in. It will most likely be faster, and is also DBMS-agnostic.

Comment: in your alternative solution you are saving the ordering(with may be optimized by mySQL any way) but yet you are selecting all the ids from the bottom

Comment: @Babibu, it will be extremely fast provided that the `id` column is indexed or is a primary key. I just tested with ~5M rows and it selected the row within a fraction of a second.

Comment: Both solutions will be fast with an index on `id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
 FROM table
 WHERE ID <= 8
 ORDER BY ID DESC
 LIMIT 1
```